# How do I add white sidebars to a webpage in html

Tags: html, css

Im Kenny and I wanted to add two left and right sidebars to may webpage so it looks like an papersheet in front of an background image.
How do I do this?

Comment: HI Kenny, on Stackoverflow you are supposed to ask your question AND show some HTML and CSS of the work you have done on your question so far. This is because there are many possiblities to achieve what your are asking for. People just need to know before they can (and are allowed) to help you. Here is a link you should read [ask]...

Comment: // , Just like in school, you must show us your work :)

Answer (score -1):

Use bootstrap, just search on Google if you don't know how to get started. You just have to add CDNs.

Then wrap your content in `<div class="container">  ~~content ~~ </div>`

Job Done!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You do not need a third party library. This is super basic CSS stuff here to the point that this is a very, very bad answer. The OP clearly has an extremely limited experience with CSS and HTML, surely a better answer would be a place to learn this stuff rather than use a library that they wouldn't understand what it's actually doing to their page?